# JQuery UI Dialog disabled in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, internet-explorer-10

I have a JQuery UI Dialog that is populated dynamically with some div and table elements depending on the contents of an array on my site, and in IE10 when I open the dialog (which works fine) the entire thing is disabled/grayed out.

The most puzzling part is that if i click on the link that displays it two times, on the second time it opens up and isn't disabled and works just fine.  The link that I click on runs this function;

```
function viewIndividualReports(){
    $("#indOrdersList").html('');
    var divHTML = "<table style='width: 685px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td style='width:20px;'><a href='#' class='toggleAllReports'></a></td><td style='vertical-align:middle; width:315px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt;'>Report</td><td style='font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt; width:140px; text-align:right; padding-right:4px; vertical-align:middle;'>Date/Time Run</td><td style='font-weight:bold; width:150px; font-size:9pt; text-align:left; padding-left:6px; vertical-align:middle;'>Status</td><td style='font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt; width:70px; vertical-align:middle;'>Delete</td></tr></table>";
    var d = new Date();
    var strDate =  (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
    var strTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    var Report1 = reportOneArray.length;
    var Report2 = reportTwoArray.length;
    divHTML += "<div id='allReports'>";
    if(Report1 > 0){
        divHTML += "<table class='sampleOneReports' style='width: 685px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr style='background-color:#D8D8D8;'><td style='vertical-align:middle; width:20px;'><a href='#' class='toggleReportOne'></a></td><td style='width:315px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:middle;'>Sample Report One</td><td style='font-weight:bold; width:140px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;'>" + strDate + "," + strTime + "</td><td style='font-weight:bold; width:150px; padding-left:6px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'><a href='#' class='viewIndReports'>View All in One PDF</a></td><td style='width:70px; vertical-align:middle;'><input type='checkbox' class='delAllSampleOne'/> All</td></tr></table><div id='sampleOneReports'><table style='width: 685px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
            for(var i = 0; i < reportOneArray.length; i = i +1 ){
                divHTML += "<tr style='background-color:#D8D8D8;'><td style='width:20px;'></td><td style='width:315px; text-align:left;'>" + reportOneArray[i]  + "</td><td style='width: 140px; text-align:right; padding-right:4px;'>&nbsp;</td><td style='width:150px; padding-left:6px; text-align:left;'><a href='#' class='viewIndReports'>View</a></td><td style='width:70px;'><input type='checkbox' id='del" + $(this).attr('advID') + "'class='delOne'/></td></tr>";
            }
        divHTML += "</table></div>";
    }
    if(Report2 > 0){
        divHTML += "<table class='sampleTwoReports' style='width: 685px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td style='vertical-align:middle; width:20px;'><a href='#' class='toggleReportTwo'></a></td><td style='width:315px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:middle;'>Sample Report Two</td><td style='font-weight:bold; width:140px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;'>" + strDate + "," + strTime + "</td><td style='font-weight:bold; width:150px; text-align:left; padding-left:6px; vertical-align:middle;'><a href='#' class='viewIndReports'>View All in One PDF</a></td><td style='width:70px; vertical-align:middle;'><input type='checkbox' class='delAllSampleTwo'/> All</td></tr></table><div id='sampleTwoReports'><table style='width: 685px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
            for(var i = 0; i < reportTwoArray.length; i = i+1){
                 divHTML += "<tr><td style='width:20px;'></td><td style='padding-top: 4px; width:315px; text-align:left;'>" + reportTwoArray[i]  + "</td><td style='width: 140px; text-align:right; padding-right:4px;'>&nbsp;</td><td style='width:150px; text-align:left; padding-left:6px;'><a class='viewIndReports' href='#' target='_blank'>View</a></td><td style='width:70px;'><input type='checkbox' id='del" + $(this).attr('advID') + "' class='delTwo'/></td></tr>";
            }
            divHTML += "</table></div>";
        }       
    divHTML += "</div>";
    $("#indOrdersList").html(divHTML);
    INDIVIDUAL_REPORTS.dialog('open');
}
```

I know it's a whole lot of dynamic tables and stuff, but it works just fine in straight IE9, but in IE10 in any version (compatibility, 7, 8, 9) it takes three instances of running that function for the dialog and elements to not be disabled.  I'd assume it doesn't have to do with my code since every time that function runs it resets the HTML that is being written to the #indOrdersList div that contains everything.  Here is also an example of the HTML that is rendered as divHTML, which looks good to me.

```
<table style='width: 685px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>
        <td style='width:20px;'>
            <a href='#' class='toggleAllReports'></a>
        </td>
        <td style='vertical-align:middle; width:315px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt;'>Report</td>
        <td style='font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt; width:140px; text-align:right; padding-right:4px; vertical-align:middle;'>Date/Time Run</td>
        <td style='font-weight:bold; width:150px; font-size:9pt; text-align:left; padding-left:6px; vertical-align:middle;'>Status</td>
        <td style='font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt; width:70px; vertical-align:middle;'>Delete</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id='allReports'>
    <table class='sampleOneReports' style='width: 685px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr style='background-color:#D8D8D8;'>
            <td style='vertical-align:middle; width:20px;'>
                <a href='#' class='toggleReportOne'></a>
            </td>
            <td style='width:315px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:middle;'>Sample Report One</td>
            <td style='font-weight:bold; width:140px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;'>10/18/2013,11:49:05 AM</td>
            <td style='font-weight:bold; width:150px; padding-left:6px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;'>
                <a href='#' class='viewIndReports'>View All in One PDF</a>
            </td>
            <td style='width:70px; vertical-align:middle;'>
                <input type='checkbox' class='delAllSampleOne'/> All
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id='sampleOneReports'>
        <table style='width: 685px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr style='background-color:#D8D8D8;'>
                <td style='width:20px;'></td>
                <td style='width:315px; text-align:left;'>AMES JOHN</td>
                <td style='width: 140px; text-align:right; padding-right:4px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style='width:150px; padding-left:6px; text-align:left;'><a href='#' class='viewIndReports'>View</a></td>
                <td style='width:70px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='delundefined'class='delOne'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style='background-color:#D8D8D8;'>
                <td style='width:20px;'></td>
                <td style='width:315px; text-align:left;'>CHIN KIM</td>
                <td style='width: 140px; text-align:right; padding-right:4px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style='width:150px; padding-left:6px; text-align:left;'>
                    <a href='#' class='viewIndReports'>View</a>
                </td>
                <td style='width:70px;'>
                    <input type='checkbox' id='delundefined'class='delOne'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <table class='sampleTwoReports' style='width: 685px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
            <td style='vertical-align:middle; width:20px;'><a href='#' class='toggleReportTwo'></a></td>
            <td style='width:315px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:middle;'>Sample Report Two</td>
            <td style='font-weight:bold; width:140px; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;'>10/18/2013,11:49:05 AM</td>
            <td style='font-weight:bold; width:150px; text-align:left; padding-left:6px; vertical-align:middle;'>
                <a href='#' class='viewIndReports'>View All in One PDF</a>
            </td>
            <td style='width:70px; vertical-align:middle;'><input type='checkbox' class='delAllSampleTwo'/> All</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id='sampleTwoReports'>
        <table style='width: 685px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr>
                <td style='width:20px;'></td>
                <td style='padding-top: 4px; width:315px; text-align:left;'>AMES JOHN</td>
                <td style='width: 140px; text-align:right; padding-right:4px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style='width:150px; text-align:left; padding-left:6px;'>
                    <a class='viewIndReports' href='#' target='_blank'>View</a>
                </td>
                <td style='width:70px;'><input type='checkbox' id='delundefined' class='delTwo'/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style='width:20px;'></td>
                <td style='padding-top: 4px; width:315px; text-align:left;'>CHIN KIM</td>
                <td style='width: 140px; text-align:right; padding-right:4px;'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style='width:150px; text-align:left; padding-left:6px;'>
                    <a class='viewIndReports' href='#' target='_blank'>View</a>
                </td>
                <td style='width:70px;'><input type='checkbox' id='delundefined' class='delTwo'/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

any help would be great 
thank you

Comment: also, all other dialog boxes on the page that don't have dynamic data run correctly without being disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the JQuery UI and JQuery version to 1.9.2 and 1.8.3 as well as the CSS, after some customization solved this issue.